# Why data from the table is not displayed?

Tags: database, laravel

I use laravel, the maximum value from the database should be displayed in my block. Previously, everything worked fine, the data was displayed up-to-date, but now for some reason the data is not displayed.

My Controller with display function:

```
    public function bust()
    {
        parent::setTitle('Crash game | ');
        $users = User::count();

$max_x = DB::table('bust_history')->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())->max('bust_number');



        return view('pages.crash', compact('users','max_x'));
    }
```

My view file:

```
<div class="header">
            <div> Max X </div>
            <div class="help"> <small>for last 24 hours</small> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body ">
            <div style="color:#48B3CD;font-size:45px;position:center;">{{$max_x}}x</div>
        </div>
```

[Here is screenshot from my DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0oT9.png)

And a screenshot of what is displayed on the site:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkaUH.png)

Who can tell me, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDIT]**

You can see the whole debug process below and in the comments. The right answer, the cause of the bug, was the type of `bust_number` column. It was a `VARCHAR` type, which caused incorrect results when trying to get the maximum value. Changing it to `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` fixed the issue, since these types can be manipulated as numbers instead of strings by MySql.

---

It is hard to give an answer since this can be caused by many things, but here are the common causes of your problem:

- You use the wrong database or the table is empty. Please double check that

```php
DB::table('bust_history')->pluck('bust_number');
```

gives you the data you expect.

- There is a problem in PHP or Carbon configuration and `Carbon::today();` is not really today (as i'm writing, `2020-01-09 00:00:00`). 
  If it is right, does

```php
DB::table('bust_history')->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())->pluck('bust_number');
```

gives you a list of `bust_number` ?

If the problem persists and you give additional details after these checks, i could edit my answer with more things to check. But in my experience, you should check what seems to be too obvious to be checked. At some point, you'll find something that's not normal.

Also, don't even use your view, just `dd($max_x);` right after the query, so you can be sure nothing interfers with your result.

Comment: All data is correct. Table `bust_history`, column is `bust_number`. No, your `->pluck` displays nothing, the column is also empty. I double checked the data, after that there is even a screenshot from the database where this data is present.

Comment: If ```DB::table('bust_history')->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())->pluck('bust_number');``` shows nothing, it means it doesn't find any data. Try without the created_at where clause. If it finds something, that means the problem is within the where clause.

Comment: I saw another oddity. I cleaned the `bust_history` table, ran the script and started to wait until the values arrived in the table. The values began to arrive in the table and the block began to be updated, but when about 50 values arrived in the table, the block began to display incorrect information. That is, the maximum number in the database is 200, 8 is displayed in the block, now nothing is clear at all ... In first screenshot it's information in block [here](https://prnt.sc/qlkf9d) and in second screenshot information from DB [here](https://prnt.sc/qlkfip). 11 it's highest, than 4...

Comment: @artyak Did you find something? Did you check the column type? It should be FLOAT or DOUBLE. If it's a VARCHAR it could cause such incorrect values. If the problem persists, can you tell me the laravel version you are using?

Comment: thank you so much. problem was with VARCHAR type. i change to Float and all fine :)

Comment: @artyak Glad to see we found the issue. I edited my answer so further readers don't have to read everything above this comment. Don't forget to accept the answer too in order to tell anybody with the same problem that it was the good solution. Wish you happy coding :)